# Cleanly Combine Two Landscapes

Tags: modeling, mesh

I used the landscape generator to create two mountain ranges.. They go edge to edge and have a weird clipping effect. I want to join them together and have the vertices joined cleanly and look normal. How could I go about this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can combine two landscape using the bridge tool.

1. Select one of the landscape in object mode and move it away from the other slightly.

   [image]
2. Select both landscapes in object mode
3. Join the two object together, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>J</kbd>

   [image]
4. In edit mode select both edge loops between the landscapes.

   [image]
5. bridge them together using the bridge tool, <kbd>W</kbd> -> Bridge Edge Loops

   - Number of Cuts: adjust this so that the generated polygons look square
   - Interpolation: Blend Surface, has the best look for bridging terrain
   - Smoothness: adjust this to your liking

   [image]

---

**Final Result**

[image]

Comment: Best answer so far. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

### Using a heightmap (first method I thought of)

Assign a gradient to both of them, from black to white along the z-axis. Render this from the top to get the combined heightmap. See this question:

[Displacement map from existing 3d geometry](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1161/how-to-make-a-displacement-map-from-existing-3d-geometry/1172#1172)

Create a new plane and assign the rendered heightmap.

### Using the shrinkwrap modifier (second and better method)

This is fairly quick, easy and gives excellent topology.

1. Join the two planes into one object.
2. Create a new plane with desired resolution. Place it over the two first.
3. Make it the same size in X-Y direction.
4. Add a shrinkwrap modifier to the new plane. Set the target to the joined terrain object.
5. Set mode to Project.
6. Make sure Negative direction is ticked.
7. Select Z direction.

Result:
[image: resulting mesh with shrinkwrap modifier settings]

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use **Boolean** modifier:

1. Select one Landscape object, enter **Edit Mode**, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> to select non-manifold edges; <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude selection; <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> > **Grid Fill**;
2. Repeat Step 1 for the other landscape object; Add **Boolean** Modifier on either one, set *Operation* to **Interset**, set *Object* to another;
3. Apply the modifier; Enter **Edit Mode**, press <kbd>X</kbd> to delete the selection (supposing you didn't change element selection in Step 1 and 2).

[image]

**NOTE:**

- You may also want to remove doubles or recalculate normals by then.
- Boolean in blender needs objects being solid. That's why we need to do like this.