# How to export texture into a file that unity can read

Tags: unity

I've just made this texture with a displacement map with the intention of using it as a terrain texture in unity, so how can i export it as a file that unity can recognize (.png)?[image: here's the texture]

Comment: sorry, I can't understand: this seems a displaced plane which also has  a "terrain" image as texture... a .png is a 2d file, do you wish to export the 3d displacement with a .png? how do you wish to use that "exported file" in unity then?

Comment: This question is not entirely clear to me either, but here are a few suggestions about what you **might** mean. 1. A displacement map. 2. A normal map. 3. A bump map. 4. A colour texture. Please let us know if either of those is what you want, and it will be a lot easier to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can bake normal maps from geometry in Blender. Unity works very well with normal maps. Follow the instructions here, but instead of baking a displacement map, bake a normal map.
[How to make a displacement map from existing 3d geometry](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1161/how-to-make-a-displacement-map-from-existing-3d-geometry)

Displacement maps work great on models with high levels of geometry. They work by displacing the models vertices based on the texture value. dense geometry does not work great in video games, because that means more faces that the computer has to render 60 times per second (usually). Instead a normal map represents lighting information for each pixel within the texture. Without deforming the actual geometry, the texture itself can receive detailed lighting information, creating the illusion of depth.