# Bake a Height Map

Tags: texture-baking

Does anyone know of a way to bake a map similar to the linear gradient node from unreal engine? Basically, I would be able to unwrap a mesh and expect every face to be colored with the correct gradient. Different from displacement in that the mesh could have multiple faces at the same xy cordinate but different z coordinates. Hell, if blender doesn't have it, let me know how to do it in other programs if you know.

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1161/how-to-make-a-displacement-map-from-existing-3d-geometry/1172#1172

Comment: Well, this question is different in that the object can have multiple faces at the same x and y coordinates, to which thta answer would not work.