# Depth camera in Blender

Tags: rendering, camera, render-passes

I would like to know if depth camera exist in blender, I mean camera that instead of returning  RGB value of each pixel return a value that is a distance to closed object?
If yes, link to some tutorials can be helpful.

Comment: there's a camera depth of field if that's what you're looking for (?), in the Properties panel > Object Data > Depth Of Field

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1161/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1555/

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for seems to be a render pass for depth. I have found that the z render pass does not really work so try the mist pass.